# Guidelines for "migration"

Tags: support, migration

I have seen a question on the main site that I believe should be migrated<sup>1</sup> to another site on the network. What are the guidelines for migrating it to another site?

- [General Guidance](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13117/58193)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Here migration means anything from formal migration to suggesting in a comment when to migrate content to a different site.</sub>

Comment: Note to visitors, please don't answer this question unless you are coming from a different site with that site's guidelines. Please comment or start a [[meta-tag:discussion]] meta post about this if needed. I'm also pingable in chat.

Comment: [Movies & TV guidance collection post here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/45378).

Comment: [Arqade guidance collection post here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15281/128160).

Comment: [Literature guidance collection post here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1420/2987).

Comment: [World Building guidance collection post here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7982/8017).

Comment: [Role-Playing Games guidance collection post here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11190/65641).

Comment: That's all the sites I plan on doing for now, potential others include Writing, Physics, Biology. Let me know if I should post there as well or somewhere else.

Comment: Wouldn't those links have more lasting value in the actual question?

Comment: @TARS They're only temporary to help keep track,  the plan is to have multiple answers here per site eventually with each site's guidance.

Comment: Perhaps also [Invented Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com). We take queries about other people's invented languages there, as well as ones members are working on.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I'd probably suggest at least combining those into a single comment containing all the links, at least in the interim, rather than 5 separate comments... :)

Answer (score 4):

### General Guidance

- **Don't migrate <s>crap</s> questions that need work**

  If the question is in need of a lot of editing, or should be closed as "Needs detail or clarity", "Needs more focus" and/or "Opinion-based" don't migrate it. It will only end up getting closed on the target site and the migration rejected.

  Informal migration is still going to cause problems for the OP if they post an identical question on the target site as it'll only end up closed again.
- **If informally migrating, consider linking the Tour or help/on-topic page instead of the homepage**

  This will make it so the user has a greater chance of finding out if their question is actually on topic there, especially if you're unsure.
- **In general only migrate to sites you're familiar with**

  To go with the previous point try and migrate to sites that you, yourself are familiar with. Not only does it create more work if it ends up not being on topic there but it also creates more confusion and annoyance to the OP who is bounced from site to site.

  If you're not familiar with the target site at the very least read their Tour page and preferably their help/on-topic page so you have an idea if the question is on topic there. Ideally there will also be a post here about migration to that site.
- **Don't migrate questions that are on topic here**

  There is overlap between Science Fiction & Fantasy and several other Stack Exchange sites. A question might be on topic on another site but that doesn't mean it is off topic here. Only migrate a question if it is off topic here *and* on topic on the target site.
- **If you're not sure, don't migrate**

  You don't have to suggest migration and if you're not sure if it needs migration or is even on topic on the target site just don't suggest it.