# Editing the Tour and Help Centre

Tags: discussion, help-center

Please check the following [main meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/345161) about what parts of the Tour and Help Centre are editable in detail. For a quick rundown though:

- Tour: Introduction paragraph
- Tour: The "Ask about..." and "Don't ask about..." bullets
- Help Centre: Introduction paragraph
- Help Centre: /help/on-topic full page

These sections are woefully out of date, with the Tour sections not having been edited since 2013 (the first revision) and so don't mention various things they probably should. One of the most notable being the Future Works Policy, especially since it's [now a close reason itself](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13445/58193)!

Should we edit these sections? If so, some things to think about:

- What needs to be mentioned for "Ask about..." and "Don't ask about..."
- There's no real detail about answering in the Tour, do we want to hack something into the Tour intro?
- /help/on-topic is completely editable, we can (ab)use this for mentioning off topic info as well
- Do we want to personalise the site more with information in the Help Centre's introduction?
- etc.

Note that something similar is being done over on [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10701/87926) for an idea that we're not really limited markdown-wise that I know of.

Please use the below community wiki answers to provide changes and the comments there to discuss any changes further.

---

Related reading:

- [How should SFF's "Ask Question" page be customised?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12936/58193)
- [New custom close reason: Future Works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13445/58193)
- [Audience-specific texts for custom close reasons: Lists of Works or Recommendations](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13305/58193)
- [Audience-specific texts for custom close reasons: Scientific Solutions or Explanations](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13275/58193)

Answer (score 4):

#### Tour: The "Don't ask about..." bullets

---

##### Current Text:

- Reading or watching recommendations
- or any other question that is primarily opinion-based
- Lists of works with a particular plot element
- or any other question with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

---

##### New Text:

- Reading or watching recommendations or any other question that is primarily opinion-based
- Questions generating discussion (do you think X?)
- [Open ended lists](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2638/58193) or any other question with too many possible answers
- Questions that would require an *extremely* long essay answer
- [Future works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5187/58193)
- [Scientific solutions or explanations](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7364/58193)

Comment: I've made some basic changes here but some of the points might want expanding upon

Answer (score 2):

#### Tour: The "Ask about..." bullets

---

##### Current Text:

- Plot, character, or setting explanations
- Historical or societal context of a work
- Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
- Story identification
- Franchise/series reading or viewing order

---

##### New Text:

- Plot, character, or setting explanations
- Historical or societal context of a work ([history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) etc.)
- Behind-the-scenes and fandom information ([behind-the-scenes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behind-the-scenes) [production](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production) etc.)
- Identification ([story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) [episode-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episode-identification) [character-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-identification) etc.)
- Franchise/series reading or viewing order ([suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) [chronological-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-order))

Comment: I added tags here and removed story from identification because it's not the only identification type we have, not sure if we want to expand here more instead of using tags?

Answer (score 0):

#### Tour: Introduction paragraph

---

##### Current Text:

> **Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about science fiction or fantasy.

---

##### New Text:

> *as yet unchanged*

Answer (score 0):

#### Help Centre: Introduction paragraph

---

*Currently blank*

Answer (score 0):

#### Help Centre: /help/on-topic full page

---

##### Current Text:

Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about:

- Plot, character, or setting explanations
- Historical or societal context of a work
- Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
- [Story identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info)
- Franchise/series reading or viewing order

#### What about other Science Fiction and Fantasy related questions?

Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange. Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here:

- Questions calling for a list of works, authors, …: *What are all the books that have X?*  *Who wrote about topic Y?*
- Reading or viewing recommendations: *I liked X, what should I watch next?*
- Genre classification: *Is X Science Fiction?*

For more information, see [the question where these topics were discussed](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic) on our meta discussion site.

If your question is about...

- **Writing science fiction or fantasy**, ask on [Writers Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com).
- **Creating a fictional situation or universe of your own or investigating the plausibility of an element of another work of fiction**, ask on [Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com).

#### My question about the site isn't answered here

Check our [community FAQ](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), and more generally our [meta-discussion site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/) (please do not ask questions about the site on the main site).

---

For more help, see ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](/help/dont-ask)

Please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer).

If your question is not specifically on-topic for Scifi & Fantasy Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

---

##### New Text:

*as yet unchanged*

Comment: "*consider asking* on Writers Stack Exchange", perhaps?

Comment: It seems pretty pointless sending people to Area 51 when the chance of them proposing a viable new site is basically nil. Better to just say that not every question has a home.

Comment: @Valorum that’s the current text that’s probably not been updated since it’s inception. It needs more improvements than just that.

Comment: We might want to mention that genre classification is acceptable on Meta:SFF.

Comment: @Valorum: Genre classification is acceptable on Meta:SFF *for the purpose of determining whether a story is on-topic*. We are not going to go into e.g. whether *Star Wars* is secretly a work of fantasy dressed up in sci-fi trappings, or some convoluted discussion like that. If you just say "genre classification is on topic on Meta," people will take that literally, and ask all sorts of nonsense.